# Converting String to ArrayList<String> in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I converted the `ArrayList<String> list` which contains `"String1"`, `"String2"` to String by using  `list.toString()`. The resulted string format is `[String1, String2]`. Is there any way to convert this result back to `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: Have a look at the `split` method of the `String` class - it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: What is preventing you from keeping the ArrayList instead of converting it to a String and back int an ArrayList?
Usually you can also convert a `ArrayList<String>` into a `String[]` with the `toArray` method.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Nothing. I just wanted to know whether `list.toString()` is reversable or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try applying the following code

```
String value = "[String1,String2,String3]";
value = value.subString(1,value.length()-1);
String[] split = value.split(",");
List<String> sampleList = Arrays.asList(split);
```

Comment: No.  This won't necessarily give an `ArrayList`, which is what the question asked for.  The right hand side of the last line needs to be `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(split))`.

Comment: @David Wallace, thanks for your suggestion. why the right hand side of the last line needs to be new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(split))? Can you please clear my doubt?

Comment: Just because the OP said he wanted to have the result as an `ArrayList`, but the specification for `Arrays.asList` doesn't require that it returns an `ArrayList`.  I believe that the current version of Java 7 _does_ in fact return an `ArrayList` from `Arrays.asList`; but it's not required to by the specification, and a future version may return something different.

Comment: @David Wallace, thank you. Will follow your valuable feedback when I work on the same in future.

Answer (score 1):

No direct way. Just get that String remove those `[]`  from String and then  split by `,`  then add back to list.

Something like this,considering the given format.

```
    String s = "[String1, String2]";
    s = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : s.split(",")) {
        list.add(string.trim());
    }
```

Comment: Note that this isn't foolproof; if the internal strings have `, ` (note the space, which should go in `split`), then you will end up with extra strings.

Answer (score 1):

create a new Class extending Array List

```
public class CustomArrayList<Item> extends ArrayList<Item> {
```

and override

> toString

method, which could give a comma separated String representation. 
Now use

`new CustomArrayList<Item>(Arrays.asList(list.toString().split(",")))`

to get it back in ArrayList.